# Code for extracting string crashes

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I wrote this code to accept a string and until where it should extract a string and print it.
Given below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int strlen(char s[]){
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i]!='\0')
        i++;
    return i;
}

char *extract(char s[], int n){
    char *result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        result[j]=s[j];
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
char str[100];
int till;
printf("Enter a string: ");
scanf("%s", str);

printf("Until where to extract: ");
scanf("%d", till);

char *ret = extract(str, till);

printf("%s is extracted", ret);

return 0;
}
```

This is what happens:

```
Enter a string: hello
Enter from where to extract: 2
```

And then it crashes.
I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: You need to `'\0'`-terminate your string.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At very first, you need to change

```
scanf("%d", till);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &till);
```

as [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) needs a *pointer to the data type* argument for the supplied format specifier. Using a wrong type of argument causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Then, there are many issues, like

1. You're allocating only 3 `char`s, where you're looping based on the incoming value of `n`.
2. You never checked for the success of `malloc()`.
3. You're not null-terminating your `result` which you intend to use as a *string* later.

That said,

1. You should always limit the input for your strings to avoid the possibility of overrun, like

   ```
   scanf("%99s", str);  //considering the length of the array is 100.
   ```
2. There is a library function [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) available with `string.h`. Even if you want to roll out your own functions, try to follow a different naming convention.
3. You did not `free()` the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

I you add -Wall to command when you compile your code you'll see

```
test.c:40:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%d", till);
  ^
```

Then change  you must change it to `scanf("%d", &till);`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions:

```
char *result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
```

Should be:

```
char *result = malloc(n + 1);
```